# Does Hibernate allow to load/save linked entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

Suppose I have self linked `Category` entity defined as follows:

```
public class Category {

@Id
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public String Url;

@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public Category Parent;

@OneToMany
private Set<Category> subs;
public void addSub(Category sub) {
    subs.add(sub);
}
public void removeSub(Category sub) {
    subs.remove(sub);
}

@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public String Title;

@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public boolean Done;
```

I wonder, will it work correctly if I create new `Category` and add it with my `addSub` method? Will `Category` be persisted correctly? Will subcategories be persisted automatically and in correct order?

Answer (score 1):

In the current state of your code - no. To make it work as you want you need to do the followng:

1. Connect sides of bidirectional relationship with `mappedBy` on `@OneToMany`, otherwise Hibernate would think that you have two different relationships:

   ```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Parent")
   ```
2. It's your responsibility to keep both sides of your relationship in consistent state:

   ```
   public void addSub(Category sub) {
       sub.setParent(this);
       subs.add(sub);  
   }
   ```

   Hibernate looks at `@ManyToOne` side when it stores the foreign key.
3. If you want subcategories of persistent `Category` to be persisted automatically, you need to configure cascading:

   ```
   @OneToMany(..., cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   ```